# How do I get this type of Paypal Checkout page?

Tags: javascript, css, paypal

I am kind of confused. I tried Paypal's smart button but that did not work yet. Now I found this from a third part app site.

How can I generate like this on my own?
Link: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/shoppingcart?flowlogging_id=6a81b5ddacc27&mfid=1595805780332_6a81b5ddacc27#/checkout/openButton

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is not a Smart Button checkout. It's an old Buy Now button checkout that's configured to allow specifying quantity.

The Smart Buttons are much better and offer an in-context checkout with no redirects, that keep you site loaded in the background.

But if, for some reason, you want to create a website with old functionality that redirects away, the old buttons can still be made at https://www.paypal.com/buttons

Comment: But I do not see any options that comes with that type of output.

Comment: That is a screenshot of a PayPal checkout page. If you create a buy now button that allows changing quantity in Step 3, it will lead to such a page. It is not a good integration method.

Comment: Oh, but it is showing some different checkout design when I tried as you said.